# OpenGL get currently bound vertex buffer and index buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently working with OpenGL in C++, and I'm trying to debug by identifying what the currently bound vertex buffer and index buffer are. I have three functions.

```
GLint getBoundVAO()
{
    GLint id = 0;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING, &id);
    return id;
};

GLint getBoundVBO()
{
    GLint id = 0;
    // ???
    return id;
};

GLint getBoundIBO()
{
    GLint id = 0;
    // ???
    return id;
};
```

How would I go about getting the vertex buffer and index buffer in a similar way to how I am getting the VAO? I've looked at the OpenGL page https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml and am not seeing a value which will allow me to get the index or vertex buffers.

Comment: The documentation for [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml#associatedgets) provides the info you need.

Comment: Be aware that the current VBO binding is pretty much useless for debugging problems. You want the buffer object associated with a particular attribute index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Parameters" section [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml). The symbolic constants used for binding the buffers match the ones used for glGet* (but with a _BINDING suffix).

For the vertex buffer object, use:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &id);
```

For the index buffer, use:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &id);
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but the values I'm getting back seem incorrect. I'm using a structure to store my IDs in-memory for testing, and getBoundVAO returns the expected value, but using these two methods I get values which are different from the ids used by my `glBind*` calls a few lines prior.

Comment: @JJ I have tested the lines from the answer and it produces the expected results. Perhaps you could ask a new question with an MVP of that particular problem?

Comment: Yes that sounds good. Thank you, I will!